# How much is the fine for arguing with an umpire?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc, finances

- How much is a player fined for arguing with an Umpire? I have heard that it is a percentage of their match fees.
- Are fines for captains different for such cases?
- Do umpires register allegations against players for arguing with them or does some authority decide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact amount depends on which category of violation defined under the ICC Code of Conduct the offence made by the offender falls . It is decided by the Match Referee and he presents his report about the incident after the end of each match to the ICC officials .  [ICC Rule Book](http://www.icc-cricket.com/rules_and_regulations.php)  here.

Excerpts:

> Any one of the following individuals can report an alleged offence
>   under the Code of Conduct (other than Minimum Over Rate Offences - as
>   to which see Appendix 2) by lodging a report in the manner described
>   in Article 3.2, below (a ‘Report’):
>
> 3.1.1 an Umpire that officiated in the International Match during which the alleged offence was committed;
>
> 3.1.2 the Team Manager or CEO of either of the two National Cricket Federations whose representative teams participated in the
>   International Match during, or in relation to which, the alleged
>   offence was committed;
>
> 3.1.3 the ICC’s Chief Executive Officer; or
>
> 3.1.4 provided it is a Level 3 Offence or Level 4 Offence that is alleged to have been committed, the Match Referee that was appointed
>   to officiate in the International Match during which the alleged
>   offence was committed. (For the avoidance of any doubt, the Match
>   Referee is not entitled to lodge a Report in relation to an alleged
>   Level 1 Offence or Level 2 Offence).`

Comment: ok what is the link for that is there any link where i can read it

Comment: I wrote from whatever I had compiled from various commentaries in this subject . You can follow this link for more :http://www.livestrong.com/article/92407-rules-cricket/

Comment: @NoobUnChained What information from either link is relevant to answering the OPs question?

Comment: `I wrote from whatever I had compiled from various oral commentaries in this subject` .

Comment: @NoobUnChained What `from various oral commentaries in this subject` is helpful in answering the OPs question?

Comment: @NoobUnChained In other words, what are the categories of violations in regards to arguing with an umpire? Where in the ICC Rule Book does it give the Match Referee said power?

Comment: Exact documentation is under Chapter 13 of ICC Rule Book : http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_700263D0BC21E1C8159D6ECA28249DBB_1298463333670_479.pdf

Answer (score 3):

There are four levels of offences - level 1, level 2, level 3 and level 4. Level one is for a lesser crime whereas level four is the most serious one.

Arguing with an umpire about a decision can fall under level 1 or 2 depending on how aggressive or offensive the player is. Intimidation or assaulting the umpire falls under level 3 and 4. At the end of the match, the umpires file a report under which all these offences are documented. The match referee, on reading this report, sends a notification to the said player(s) and a disciplinary meeting is called where appropriate action (warning/fine/suspension) is taken against the player.

Based on the frequency (over a 12 month period) and offence level, the fines vary. The fine-list can be found in [Article 7.3](http://static.icc-cricket.com/ugc/documents/DOC_988F9785FD768E4902737F0ACA2E856B_1352699795637_343.pdf) of the ICC Code of Conduct for players.